# CSS WordPress box within a box

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm having trouble with WordPress, nesting box within a box.
Outside of WordPress this works fine. I'm sure there's just one or two parameters wrong.

The outer box is dp23, the inner box is dp22
For some reason there is spacing between the inner boxes (dp22) .
you can see the problem here: http://4tepiano.com/recommended-piano-books-2/

CSS code:

```
 .dp101
 {
 float:left; 
 width:100%; 
 border:1px solid green;
 display: inline;
 clear: both;
 margin:auto;
 } 

 .dp75 {
 width:84%;
 border-color:gray;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:1px;
 overflow:auto;
 float: right;
 text- align:left;
 padding:10px;
 }

 .dp22 {
  border:1px solid red;
  HEIGHT: 1.2em;
  margin:1px;
  padding:1px;
  font-size: .8em;
  overflow:auto;
  display: block;
  }
  .dp23 {
  width:12%;
  border:1px solid green;
  float:left;
  margin:1px;
  padding:1px;
  }
    [edited]
  .dp23 p {
  display: none;
  }
```

Html Code:

```
 <div class="dp101" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #fdfcdc">
  <div class="dp23" style="HEIGHT: 150px";><!--Left Column-->
  <!--category--> <div class="dp22">        category                 </div>
  <!--Title-->   <div class="dp22" >    Title                   </div>
  <!--Author-->  <div class="dp22" >    Author                     </div>
 <!--Price-->   <div class="dp22">   Price                      </div>
 <!--Link-->    <div class="dp22"> Amazon Link       </div>
 <!--Cover-->   <div class="dp22" style= "HEIGHT: 85px"; >                      Cover                   </div>

 </div>           <!--End-Left Column-->

                 <!--Right Column-->
 <div class="dp75"style="HEIGHT: 150px"; >             

     Work in progress. 
        </div> <!--End-Right Column-->

 <div class="dp75" style="HEIGHT: 10px";> <!--Right spacer--> </div>
```

I have used borders to make it easy to see. The boxes should be stacked together, with the borders touching each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have empty `<p>` tags between those elements - they actually have comments in them..

[image]

Remove the `<p>` elements between `dp22`, and your problem is solved.

Because your coding above doesn't demonstrate this, I am going to assume that wordpress is generating these `<p>` tags.. I suggest removing all the unnecessary spacing in your HTML.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary ones, however I want each div to be on a separate line, and WordPress inserts those paragraphs.

Comment: Remove the spacing between the `divs` and wordpress wont generate those paragraphs.. also if you want the `divs` to be on separate lines use `display:block`.. make sure they are not set to `inline`

Comment: I edited the code. But the problem still exists. Because each div is separate line, WordPress is inserting those paragraphs. That's why I changed the paragraph property in db23. but it still does not work.

Comment: Apparently this is a well-known WordPress problem. But I would not have found it without your help. Thank you.

Comment: I have to remove the box within the box. Only one now, and let wordpress manage it.

Answer (score 1):

You have random `<p>` tags in your code between your dp22 `<div>`s. They look somewhat like this:

```
<p>
   <!--Author-->
</p>
```

Remove them or include the following code in your CSS:

```
p {
   display: none;
}
```

Though that may cause other problems if you are actually using `<p>` tags elsewhere.

Comment: 1+ You beat me to this by a couple seconds.. but I don't think its good advice to use `display:none` as you said, this will cause other problems.. but additionally, the problem shouldn't be masked; but rather, just removed.

Comment: I think I can set p for that box only. apparently WordPress is doing that.

Comment: I agree with JoshC. If you can, try to get rid of the `<p>` tags.